# "Configuration is not a module (TypeError)" Errror after installing ShareMeow gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've been following [this tutorial](https://gorails.com/episodes/sharemeow), to install the [ShareMeow gem](https://github.com/producthunt/ShareMeowClient) in my rails app.

After adding the gem to my gem-file and the configuration variables in an initializer I run into this error.

```
.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/share_meow_client-0.1.3/lib/helpers/configuration.rb:18:in 
`<main>': Configuration is not a module (TypeError)
```

After googling this error, I suspect that I'm getting this error because my rails-app already use 'Configuration' as a class somewhere else in the app?

Any ideas on how I can get around this to use this gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.

You can fork the gem and move `Configuration` into `ShareMeowClient::` namespace. Then use the fork instead of the original gem with `gem 'share_meow_client', github: 'you/ShareMeowClient'`. You can even send this change upstream.

Alternatively, you can rename `Configuration` class in your app to something else (e.g. `AppConfiguration`) so that it doesn't clash with the one from the gem.

Or you can just copy the implementation of [`image_url`](https://github.com/producthunt/ShareMeowClient/blob/master/lib/share_meow_client.rb#L37-L45) method to your app and not use the gem at all. This is what I would prefer. The gem looks like abandonware anyway, last update is 5 years ago. It's only a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks! I did a quick test with the 3rd option and that seemed to work fine. :) 

Where would you recommend to put this file? Currently, I added it into my Models folder but I guess maybe the Lib folder is better for this?

Comment: I am not sure. Probably `lib`. Or `app/services`.